# How do I modify the 'Format' dropdown in CKEditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm trying to modify the 'Format' drop down in CKEditor, and I think I've followed all the instructions properly, but it's not working.

I went to _source/plugins/format/plugin.js and changed

```
CKEDITOR.config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div';
```

to

```
CKEDITOR.config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;div;p';
```

When I add a 'Format' drop down though, I still get all the original options in there (`p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div`) instead of just the ones I listed.

Am I editing the wrong file or something?  Or do I need to do something else to make it realise that the option has changed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should edit your config file, not the plugin file.

Should be in the root of the `ckeditor` folder, `config.js`

Should start with:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
```

So you would want to add this to it (after the above, but before the closing `}`):

```
config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;div;p';
```

Comment: For the <p> tag, it says "Normal".  Is there a way to change that to say "Paragraph"

Thanks

Comment: @Brett You will need to override the entry in the language file: `CKEDITOR.lang.en.format.tag_p = "Paragraph"`

Answer (score 1):

Nick is right. You shouldn't touch the source folder. Just use the config.js file located in ckeditor root. Also refer to [the CKEditor API page](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.format_tags) for further customization options and the [developer guides here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide).